# Convert image to base64 javascript on firefox

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, base64

I need to convert image that are in a webpage to base64 over greasemonkey or firefox .xpi extension.
How can i do it?
I know that i have btoa() function, but i only can use it with strings, not with images.
Little help here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `canvas` element and draw the image using `drawImage()` onto it, then use `toDataURL()` to get the base64 encoded image.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/canvas

Comment: In order to use canvas element this would not be fine, because i'm doing a script to interact with another page. There's not another way? Or can i use that functions without calling canvas element?

Comment: Maybe there is another way, but for those functions mentioned, you need a `canvas` element

Comment: Ok, could you please give me a example?

Comment: Found a good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript/934925#934925